# Get Enum constant by value

Tags: java, enums

I want to create a method, which returns enum constants by it's value.

I have multiple enum classes which looks like this one (some of them have getter variables with different names):

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum PhoneType {

MOBILE("Mobile", 3),
HOME("Home", 6),
WORK("Work", 7);

@Getter
String type;

@Getter
int id;
}
```

I used this stream to get the enum constant:

```
int phoneTypeId = 3;

PhoneType phoneType = Arrays.stream(PhoneType.values())
   .filter(p -> p.getId() == phoneTypeId)
   .findFirst()
   .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Not able to find Enum...."));

System.out.println(phoneType.getType());
```

*output is: "Mobile"*

Now I want to create a method which will work for different enum classes. I started with something like this, but I don't know how to rewrite the filter line, to make it work for any enum class. It would be ideal to pass this *"p -> p.getId() == phoneTypeId"* as input parameter to this method. Any ideas?

```
public static <E extends Enum<?>> E getEnumByValue(Class<E> enumClass) {
    return Arrays.stream(enumClass.getEnumConstants())
            .filter(p -> p.getId() == phoneTypeId)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Not able to find Enum...."));
}
```

(I know that it's possible to do that if I implement interface for all enum classes, but then enum variables would have to have the same names.)

Comment: I'd rather have a `static Map<Integer, PhoneType>` to have a lookup in O(1) instead of iterating over the values each time (O(n)). Such a map can be easily initialised directly from within `PhoneType` FYI: `Stream.of(values()).collect(toMap(PhoneType::getId, identity()))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass it as a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html):

```
public static <E extends Enum<?>> Optional<E> getEnumByValue(Class<E> enumClass, Predicate<E> predicate) {
    return Arrays.stream(enumClass.getEnumConstants())
            .filter(predicate)
            .findFirst();
}
```

(Note: the method should actually return an `Optional<E>`)

If all enums have ids, you can still implement a common interface:

```
interface Identifiable {
    int getId();
}

enum PhoneType implements Identifiable {
    ...
}

public static <E extends Enum<?> & Identifiable> Optional<E> getEnumById(Class<E> enumClass, int id) {
    return Arrays.stream(enumClass.getEnumConstants())
            .filter(e -> e.getId() == id)
            .findFirst();
}

Optional<PhoneType> phone = getEnumById(PhoneType.class, phoneTypeId);
```

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for.
(I'm throwing exception if it's not found instead of returning Optional<E>, I forgot to copy these lines...)